# Convert date Y-m-d to MongoDate

Tags: mongodb

I need a query to optimize my data from a collection and convert all fields `date_passport` from Y-m-d format to MongoDate format, thats possible just with mongo query?

Currently:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("522e261a7ecb75b34e000000"),
    type: "Chat",
    last_name: "Test",
    date_passport: '2013-11-28'
}
```

Needed:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("522e261a7ecb75b34e000000"),
    type: "Chat",
    last_name: "Test",
    date_passport: ISODate("2013-11-28T02:00:00.%LZ")
}
```

Comment: You'd need to convert the data. You could do it from the MongoDB console. Just loop through each and update the `validade_pass` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how I solve this:

If your date is dd/mm/YYYY

```
db.customer.find(
    {
        date_passport : {$nin : ['', undefined]} // find for not is empty or undefined documents
    }
).forEach( function(obj) {
    if (typeof(obj.date_passport)!='object') { //check if is not already a ISODate
        var datePt = obj.date_passport.split('/'); //split the string dd/mm/YYYY
        var dateEn = datePt[2] + '-' + datePt[1] + '-' + datePt[0]; // reorganize to YYYY-mm-dd

        obj.date_passport = new ISODate(dateEn); // convert in ISODate
        db.customer.save(obj); //save and thats all
    }
});
```

If your data is already YYYY-mm-dd

```
db.customer.find(
    {
        date_passport : {$nin : ['', undefined]} // find for not is empty or undefined documents
    }
).forEach( function(obj) {
    if (typeof(obj.date_passport)!='object') { //check if is not already a ISODate
        obj.date_passport = new ISODate(obj.date_passport); // convert in ISODate
        db.customer.save(obj); //save and thats all
    }
});
```

Comment: Also, `YYYY-mm-dd` is [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format so it is more portable and supported. ISO 8601 should be used if anyone want to store date as string.

Comment: But, if I need to query dates on mongodb my date field need to be as a object ISODate right? I mean, work with dates like mysql. The way I see, store my dates on mongo using string YYYY-mm-dd is like doing the same on mysql (store date as string type, not date) this way keep data hard to work with.

Comment: I agree with your point. I use ISO 8601 when sending date in JSON (`Date.toISOString()` or custom format to `YYYY-mm-dd`) and sometimes I use it as literal string field in db only when *no range comparison is needed*.